# Tabs Not Working

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tabs, zurb-foundation

I can't seem to get tabs to work. I copied and pasted the code from the Foundation docs, and the tabs show up properly, but the content does not change when I click on them. It just displays the content for the first tab.

[This is the page I am working on.](http://oakwood.slamagency.com/consulting/)

If it helps to know, I am working on a child theme of Reverie.

EDIT: Here's the code from the Foundation Tabs page that I am using:

```
<dl class="tabs vertical" data-tab>
  <dd class="active"><a href="#panel1a">Tab 1</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel2a">Tab 2</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel3a">Tab 3</a></dd>
  <dd><a href="#panel4a">Tab 4</a></dd>
</dl>
<div class="tabs-content vertical">
  <div class="content active" id="panel1a">
    <p>Panel 1 content goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel2a">
    <p>Panel 2 content goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel3a">
    <p>Panel 3 content goes here.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="content" id="panel4a">
    <p>Panel 4 content goes here.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post the code you are using?

Comment: It's the same code that's on the Foundation tabs page. See edit above.

Comment: All you are showing is the HTML - is there any JavaScript code to go with it??

Comment: I thought the js was included with Foundation?

Comment: Do you see any on your page?

Comment: I see this ` <script src="http://oakwood.slamagency.com/wp-content/themes/reverie-master/js/foundation.min.js" type="text/javascript">
 
 <script>
 (function($) {
 $(document).foundation();
 })(jQuery);
 </script>`

Comment: Unless you can get a copy of that file I don't know if there is anything we can do except rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: It's a fairly big file. If you go to the page and view the source, you'll see it at the bottom. Do you want me to copy all of it here?

Answer (score 0):

The foundation file you have is ©2013, and 200+ lines. The current Foundation 5 file is ©2014 and 163 lines. Perhaps there is a version issue? Try to update the file with the most current F5 js file and see if that helps.

In searching the source of your "example" there is no mention of the actual "tabs-vertical" lass and the tabs containers... has it been removed? It's hard to test a page without the code actually on it...

Your code shown here is syntactically correct so the error must be within the JS file somewhere/somehow.

Click this link (Line 312) in the source to see the ©2013 Zurb file.
In addition.. you are calling two files so this may be the problem too...

[image]

Comment: Where do you see that it is ©2013? The one I see is ©2014. Also, the link should be working now to show the page with the tabs.

Comment: Line 312 in your source links to a 2013 Zurb file. In addition, line 315 links to the 2014 version. you may have a conflict with both being loaded...

Comment: Looks like that 2013 file is coming from the Foundation Shortcodes plugin. I tried disabling the plugin, but the tabs still don't work. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does anyone else have any ideas? I'm not sure what to do next, and I need the tabs to work.